# How to Prevent Files Created with GetTempFileName Being Automatically Deleted upon Reboot

Tags: windows, winapi, temporary-files

Our application collects data from an external device.  This data primarily resides in memory, but is spooled to disk in temporary files until the user explicitly saves the data.  This is to provide some recovery chance if the application crashes for some reason.  Generally speaking, it works just fine.

Lately we've discovered, thanks to Windows becoming more forceful about automatic updates, that these files get deleted automatically during a reboot.  So if Windows kills our application to automatically apply updates, the temporary files that would have allowed recovery are gone after the reboot.

I've tested the issue by killing the application on purpose and rebooting; indeed, the temporary files have vanished after the reboot.

The files are created using the Win32 API call `GetTempFileName`, along with `GetTempPath`.  Everything I've read on the subject says these files are **not** automatically deleted ever, but they clearly are being deleted.

What can I do to stop this?  Or should I just change where our safety data is stored?

Comment: You created a *temporary* file, and are now asking for it to behave like a permanent file. If you want a permanent file, don't create a temporary file.

Comment: @IInspectable you make a fair point, and I suppose we are stretching the idea of 'temporary' file.  But it is temporary in that it's only there in case something goes horribly wrong, and I'd still like to see some documentation explaining the automatic deletion; so far, I haven't found any.

Comment: Don't store them in `GetTempFileName` but store them somewhere in LocalAppdata. Use [SHGetFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) to retrieve the location of LocalAppData.

Comment: If the temporary file is being deleted only on reboot and not just to do with when program closes, it means there is likely data about this pending operation stored somewhere (e.g. registry). Do a re-test but before you reboot, check HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations and see if your temporary file is there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution IMO is not using the temporary folder which contains (as the name suggests) temporary files that can be deleted without any consequences.

Instead you should store them somewhere in the LocalAppdata folder.

Use [SHGetFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha) function to retrieve the actual location of the LocalAppData folder.

In LocalAppData create a folder whose name is that of your company and/or product name or some combination of both and store all your pseudo temporary files there.

Answer (score 6):

What you are seeing is a new "Storage Sense" feature added in Windows 10.

[How to Clear Temporary Files Automatically in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/blog/clear-temporary-files-automatically-windows-10/).

> Windows 10 got the ability to clear temporary files automatically in a recent build. Starting with build 15014, a new option appeared in Settings.

[image]

When enabled, it can be set to clear items like temporary files, Recycle Bin, etc.  You can turn them off individually.

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, another option would be to change your app to save its temporary files in a non-system temp folder that you control, rather than using `GetTempPath()`.  And maybe also use something other than `GetTempFileName()` to create your temporary file names (like using date/times or guids instead), so Windows can't possibly track the temporary files you create.  Then perhaps your files won't be deleted automatically by Storage Sense anymore.

Comment: Good answer, +1 from me.  The real issue, IMHO, is that older versions of Windows didn't do this in the first place so the files just built up and up.  There is always pain in any transition, but this one, I reckon, is worth it.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I can reproduce the behavior on Windows 7; perhaps MS ported that feature to 7 as well. Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @BrianA.Henning MS did not backport Storage Sense to Windows 7. Something else is deleting your files at startup. A boot script, an auto-start app, a disk cleaner, etc.